# Hypothesis Testing on Renewal Processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, hypothesis-testing

> We have time $[0,T]$ to observe a renewal point process, where the inter-renewal timings are i.i.d, and then decide whether the observation is according to a renewal process in which the pdf of inter-renewal process is  $p(x)$ or $q(x)$.
>
> We want to do this hypothesis testing in such a way that the sum of error probabilities (type I error and type II error) is minimum. What is the sum of error probabilities in this case?

I have solved this problem for the case that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are two exponential distributions so the renewal processes are Poisson. Can you please help to solve it for the general case?

Comment: Well, the test that does this is the likelihood ratio test with threshold one. So, it would help to show how you applied this in the Poisson process case and where it went wrong for the general case.

Comment: For easy access, also posted on CrossValidated here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210542/hypothesis-testing-to-discriminate-between-two-renewal-processes

Comment: Sure, I will provide my answer for the Poisson. Why the test that you said is the optimal test?

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks a lot for your comment.

Comment: @Batman The Poisson case is easy, since it has a lot of interesting properties and the one which helps is that it is enough to just base your hypothesis test on the number of arrivals in duration $[0,T]$.  For a general case, to build the likelihood ratio test, I need to first characterize the general renewal process by a pdf function. I don't know how to do that but I thought there might be a rich literature about it which I have not seen yet, and other people like you may direct me.

Comment: I give a try for the general formulation: Suppose the inter-renewal times $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ and the current life $\displaystyle \delta = t - \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ are observed. So we construct the likelihood ratio as $\displaystyle \Lambda = \frac {\int_{\delta}^{\infty} p(x)dx}{\int_{\delta}^{\infty} q(x)dx}\prod_{i=1}^n \frac {p(x_i)} {q(x_i)}$. We classify the times $X \sim p$ when $\Lambda > c$, and $X \sim q$ otherwise. We choose the constant $c$ by minimizing the sum of misclassification rates $\mathbb{P}\{\Lambda < c\} + \mathbb{Q}\{\Lambda > c\}$.